# Reform Conversions and Olam Ha-Ba

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, olam-haba-world-to-come, reform-judaism, afterlife

If a Gentile decides to convert through the Reform movement for the purposes of being ethically monotheistic, practicing traditions relating to Judaism, and having a community, would they be punished for this in the Afterlife?

**Assuming that the convert goes through a bet dien, circumcision, and Mikvah

**By traditions I mean things like lighting Shabbat candles, observing the holidays,bar/bat mitzvahs, not eating foods regarded as trief by the Torah, etc

Comment: Why would you convert to Reform Judaism? Is there a specific reason you would pick the Reform movement over Orthodox Judaism?

Comment: Generally, questions about Olam haBa are difficult to answer. One could posit that if someone deliberately chose Reform over Orthodoxy (with a complete understanding of the tenets of both), then it would like denying the binding nature of the mitzvot, but still claiming to be a Jew, and that would be heresy according to Orthodoxy.

Comment: The Reform *conversion* is not valid so the question would be *if someone is mistaken about being Jewish, what should he do?*